# How to call an action inside another action in Yii?

Tags: ajax, yii

I've a situation where i get some information from database and based on the data , i want to do/forward to some other controller & action.

How can i do this using Yii? Its like an ajax request..

If i can use the CController->forward() , then how can use the post values for actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I shall assume that the reason why redirect() didn't work for you was because you can't sent post variables with it. If that's the case, then let me show you how to overcome the lack of POST support in redirect(). You can use `setState()`. It creates variables that simulate POST variables. This is the code to store or set a variable:

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('var', 'value');
```

And, in order to trace the value you just code as follows:

```
Yii::app()->user->getState('param1');
```

It would equally work with forward, but I'm not sure why you want to use it instead of redirect().

Comment: maybe because redirect() changes the url, and forward() doesn't, @Vijay wants an ajax kind of request. user state is a good idea though to pass parameters, +1.